# Undeclared identifier in the signature of a function which takes a function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a program which utilises a custom BST which I need to pass in a function pointer which takes certain data from the BST and puts it into a `vector`.

Given the following code I get an error `error C2065: 'result' : undeclared identifier` at the line `process(nodePtr->value, result);`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

main.cpp

```
int main() {
    //...
    //do some things and get some data into a custom binary search tree
    //...
    vector<CustomStruct>* result = new vector<CustomStruct>;
    void (*putValuesIntoAVectorFPtr)(CustomStruct, vector<CustomStruct>*) = &putValuesIntoAVector;

    myCustomBinarySearchTree->inOrderTraversal(putValuesIntoAVectorFPtr, result);
}

void putValuesIntoAVector(CustomStruct data, vector<CustomStruct>* result) {
    //do something
}
```

Bst.h

```
class Bst {
    public:
        void inOrderTraversal(void (*process)(T, vector<T>*), vector<T>* result);
    private:
        void inOrder(node<T>* nodePtr, void (*process)(T, vector<T>*), vector<T>* result);
};

template <class T>
void Bst<T>::inOrderTraversal(void (*process)(T, vector<T>* result), vector<T>* result) {
    inOrder(root, process, result);
}

template <class T>
void Bst<T>::inOrder(node<T>* nodePtr, void (*process)(T, Vector<T>*), Vector<T>* result) {
    if(nodePtr->left != nullptr) {
        inOrder(nodePtr->left, process);
    }
    process(nodePtr->value, result);
    if(nodePtr->right != nullptr) {
        inOrder(nodePtr->right, process);
    }
}
```

--edit--

Fixed code based on suggestion by @WhozCraig

Working now

Comment: `result` is part of your function pointer parameter declaration (and is somewhat pointless where it appears). There is no `result` parameter for `inOrder` as you have it declared; only a node pointer and a function pointer. Thus, `process(nodePtr->value, result);` has no idea what `result` is, and therefore, your error.

Comment: of course... ill fix that up and edit the question if I still have difficulty